# Symbolic calculation

Tags: symbolic

Is there any software where this kind of symbolic calculation is possible?

```
s = 0
for i = 1 to m
   j = 2 i + a - t
   if (j > 0) s = s + a
```

I want s as a function of m,a,t, where m,a,t are integers. This is a toy example. In my calculation a lot of if/else, minimum of two values, etc., are involved.

Comment: _Mathematica_ can certainly handle this, but I don't see this a symbolic calculation if all the actual arguments are going to be integer values. I suggest you elaborate on how you intend to use unbound symbols in your work.

Comment: @m_goldberg perhaps he means to evaluate his statement symbolically into closed form.  OP, could you please clarify?

Comment: Otherwise, OP, I recommend taking a look at [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/VariablesAndFunctions.html). What you wrote in psuedocode can easily be transcribed into MMA.

Comment: Yes, I want closed form of s. Will you kindly explain how to write this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you, then:

```
Sum[Boole[2 i + a - t > 0] a, {i, 1, m}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I gotta learn how to use `Boole` better!

Comment: @user46185 I see that you Accepted this answer.  Were you able to adapt this to your larger problem?  You mentioned "a lot of if/else" -- generally you want to use `Boole` and `Piecewise` which are mathematical constructs rather than `If`/`Which` etc. flow control functions, when using `Sum`, `Product` etc. to compute a symbolic equivalent.